# libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linker, undefined-reference

When I'm compiling openvswitch-1.5.0, I've encountered the following compile error:

```
 gcc -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-arith
     -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wformat-security -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-parameter -Wstrict-aliasing -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wno-override-init  -g -O2 -export-dynamic ***-lpthread***  -o utilities/ovs-dpctl utilities/ovs-dpctl.o lib/libopenvswitch.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_eal.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/libethdev.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_cmdline.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_hash.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_lpm.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_mbuf.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_ring.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_mempool.a
 /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_malloc.a -lrt -lm 
     /usr/bin/ld: /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_eal.a(eal.o): undefined reference
     to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from 
     command line
```

If I try to see the symbols of `libpthread`, it looks fine.

```
$ readelf -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 | grep pthread_create
   199: 0000000000008220  2814 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   173: 0000000000008220  2814 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __pthread_create_2_1
   462: 0000000000008220  2814 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2
```

Could you give any hints or pointers?

Comment: Also see [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19901934), [DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24096807), and [Linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24989432).

Comment: link_libraries(pthread)

Comment: #  readelf -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
readelf: Error: Could not locate '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so'.  System error message: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You should mention the library on the command line *after* the object files being compiled:

```
 gcc -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wformat-security -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-parameter -Wstrict-aliasing -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wno-override-init \
     -g -O2 -export-dynamic -o utilities/ovs-dpctl utilities/ovs-dpctl.o \
     lib/libopenvswitch.a \
     /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_eal.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/libethdev.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_cmdline.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_hash.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_lpm.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_mbuf.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_ring.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_mempool.a /home/jyyoo/src/dpdk/build/lib/librte_malloc.a \
     -lrt -lm -lpthread
```

Explanation: the linking is dependent on the order of modules. Symbols are first requested, and then linked in from a library that has them. So you have to specify modules that use libraries first, and libraries after them. Like this:

```
gcc x.o y.o z.o -la -lb -lc
```

Moreover, in case there's a circular dependency, you should specify the same library on the command line several times. So in case `libb` needs symbol from `libc` and `libc` needs symbol from `libb`, the command line should be:

```
gcc x.o y.o z.o -la -lb -lc -lb
```

Comment: I think you can do `-Wl,--start-group -la -lb- -lc -Wl,--end-group` for circular dependencies.

Comment: Note this also applies to source files--they should be listed before libraries. You can think of the resulting object files taking the place of the source files in the command line, and apply the same order as above.

Answer (score 90):

**Background**

The `DSO missing from command line` message will be displayed when the linker does not find the required symbol with it's normal search but the symbol is available in one of the dependencies of a directly specified dynamic library.

In the past the linker considered symbols in dependencies of specified languages to be available. But that changed in some later version and now the linker enforces a more strict view of what is available. The message thus is intended to help with that transition.

**What to do?**

**If you are the maintainer of the software**

You should solve this problem by making sure that all libraries that are needed to satisfy the needed symbols are directly specified on the linker command line. Also keep in mind that order often matters.

**If you are just trying to compile the software**

As a workaround it's possible to switch back to the more permissive view of what symbols are available by using the option `-Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries`. Put this option before the linked libraries, like `g++ main.cc -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -ltensorflow`

Common ways to inject this into a build are to export LDFLAGS before running `configure` or similar like this:

```
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries"
```

Sometimes passing `LDFLAGS="-Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries"` directly to `make` might also work.

Comment: gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) didn't recognize this flag.

Comment: It's not a gcc option, so either you are missing the `-Wl,` bit, or you have an linker that does not support this options. What linker are you using? This answer assumes the classic binutils linker(ld.bfd). The binutils gold linker(ld.gold) documents `--copy-dt-needed-entries` as "Not supported". So if you have that (or any other linker that does not support this option) as default you might need to follow the section for maintainers or switch to the classic ld for linking. I think you can use `-fuse-ld=ld.bfd` for that.

Comment: This is the right answer if you are using g++ for C++ It describes the technical details and it gives the correct solution. The fact this answer does these things makes it the best. The fact that there are other issues in play causes this answer to be buried by "Use G++/Use GCC" answers that won't help if the seeker is using the right compiler.

Comment: worth noting that this has to be BEFORE the target library so e.g. `g++ sound.o -o soundprogram -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -lsfml-audio`

Comment: To find the dependency you need, try `scanelf`. I got error `undefined reference to symbol '_ZNK10...Ev'` and diagnosed with `scanelf -l -s _ZNK10...Ev | grep _ZNK10...Ev`, which returned /usr/lib/libtensorflow.so, /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so, and /usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so. I tried permutations of lib flags, and solved with `-ltensorflow -ltensorflow_framework`.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103744

Answer (score 60):

The error message depends on distribution / compiler version:

Ubuntu Saucy:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/root/ffmpeg-2.1.1//libavformat/libavformat.a(http.o): undefined reference to symbol 'inflateInit2_'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Ubuntu Raring: (more informative)

```
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'uncompress' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
```

**Solution:** You may be missing a library in your compilation steps, during the linking stage. In my case, I added '-lz' to makefile / GCC flags.

**Background:** DSO is a dynamic shared object or a shared library.

Comment: I used this solution building another project that was giving the same error by adding -lz to the LDFLAGS and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The error still remain for me:  /usr/bin/ld: gaSim.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1'
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Comment: In part solved adding '-lpthread', but now it shows me:   gaSim.c:(.text+0x11d6): undefined reference to `glewInit'

Comment: @Aerox: for `glewInit`, you need `-lGLEW`

Comment: thank you for spelling out the acronym.

Answer (score 14):

I found another case and therefore I thing you are all wrong.

This is what I had:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: eggtrayicon.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XFlush'
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

The problem is that the command line DID NOT contain `-lX11` - although the libX11.so should be added as a dependency because there were also GTK and GNOME libraries in the arguments.

So, the only explanation for me is that this message might have been intended to **help you**, but it didn't do it properly. This was probably simple: the library that provides the symbol was not added to the command line.

Please note three important rules concerning linkage in POSIX:

- Dynamic libraries have defined dependencies, so only libraries from the top-dependency should be supplied in whatever order (although after the static libraries)
- Static libraries have just undefined symbols - it's up to you to know their dependencies and supply all of them in the command line
- The order in *static* libraries is always: **requester first**, **provider follows**. Otherwise you'll get undefined symbol message, just like when you forgot to add the library to the command line
- When you specify the library with `-l<name>`, you never know whether it will take `lib<name>.so` or `lib<name>.a`. The dynamic library is preferred, if found, and static libraries only can be enforced by compiler option - that's all. And whether you have any problems as above, it depends on whether you had static or dynamic libraries
- Well, sometimes the dependencies may be lacking in dynamic libraries :D

Comment: It is not only intended to help you, it is required by the linker to resolve the names in question. The error is completely valid. If the compiler decided to let that through, you would just get a segfault for accessing something that isn't there in the binary runtime.

Comment: To add, it is possible that on different platforms, the source is compiled differently; what is linked on one system may not be linked on another. This is usually not the case, but it is 100% plausible.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's not valid, but that it's not exactly helpful to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I also encountered same problem. I do not know why, i just add `-lpthread` option to compiler and everything ok.

Old:

```
$ g++ -rdynamic -m64 -fPIE -pie  -o /tmp/node/out/Release/mksnapshot ...*.o *.a -ldl -lrt
```

got following error. If i append `-lpthread` option to above command then OK.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/node/out/Release/obj.host/v8_libbase/deps/v8/src/base/platform/condition-variable.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_condattr_setclock@@GLIBC_2.3.3'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This worked for me; I had to add a second, "redundant" -lpthread to the g++ command in the makefile that does the link.  (It already appeared once in the LIBS list in the makefile.)  I also added "-L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" to the LDFLAGS definition in the makefile.

Answer (score 7):

I found I had the same error. I was compiling a code with both lapack and blas. When I switched the order that the two libraries were called the error went away.

"LAPACK_LIB = -llapack -lblas" worked where
"LAPACK_LIB = -lblas -llapack" gave the error described above.

Comment: I get this error in a cmake-defined project... so is there a bug in Cmake that puts the linker order wrong?

Comment: replying to @peterkarasev : try using `find_package(Threads)` and `target_link_libraries( ... ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using CMake, there are some ways that you could solve it:

**Solution 1:** The most elegant one

```
add_executable(...)
target_include_directories(...)
target_link_libraries(target_name pthread)
```

**Solution 2:** using CMake `find_package`

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED) # this will generate the flag for CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT

add_executable(...)
target_include_directories(...)
target_link_libraries(target_name ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

**Solution 3:** Change CMake flags

```
# e.g. with C++ 17, change to other version if you need
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -pthread")
```

Answer (score 3):

What I have found is that sometimes the library that the linker complains about is not the one causing the problem. Possibly there is a clever way to work out where the problem is but this is what I do:

- Comment out all the linked libraries in the link command.
- Clean out all .o's, .so's etc (Usually make clean is enough, but you may want to run a recursive find + rm, or something similar).
- Uncomment the libraries in the link command one at a time and re-arrange the order as necessary.

@peter karasev: I have come across the same problem with a gcc 4.8.2 cmake project on CentOS7. The order of the libraries in "target_link_libraries" section is important. I guess cmake just passes the list on to the linker as-is, i.e. it doesn't try and work out the correct order. This is reasonable - when you think about it cmake can't know what the correct order is until the linking is successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

Please add: `CFLAGS="-lrt"` and `LDFLAGS="-lrt"`

Answer (score 2):

When working with code that uses mathematical functions, you should also link them.
In my Case when compiling I provided the following, which worked for me.

```
mpicc -o testname testname.c -lm
```

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me when I use `distcc` to make my c++ project;
Finally I solved it with `export CXX="distcc g++"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `-pthread` at the end of the library list in the *Makefile*.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using cmake and used pthreads, try add the following lines

```
find_package(Threads)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile with g++ instead. It has worked in my case switching from gcc to g++.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me as I was installing the HPCC benchmark (includes HPL and a few other benchmarks). I added `-lm` to the compiler flags in my build script and then it successfully compiled.

Comment: This does neither answer this specific question nor give a general answer for a family of similar problems. This is a highly localized answer for *another question entirely*.

Answer (score 0):

If using `g++`, make sure that you are not running `gcc` instead

Comment: Why? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @IvanIvković well, gcc is the C compiler, g++ is the C++ compiler. While C++ can compile C, gcc cannot compile C++.