# Boost linking error undefined reference to GLIBCXX_3.4

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to link with boost, using clang under ubuntu. And I get following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've added find_package(Boost COMPONENTS file_system, system) to cmake. Any idea what may cause this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line

Comment: I've checked cmake generated build command and linking is after objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error was because Boost was build using gcc standard library libstdc++ and I was compiling using clang libc++.

Previously I was using Boost downloaded with apt-get. Downloading sources from boost.org and compiling by hand using clang and its standard library fixed this problem.

Comment: I got a similar message, when switching from `g++` to `clang++` I accidentally typed `clang` instead (C-only/automatic compiler, which means among other things that it didn't like correctly to `libc++`).