# DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, linux, g++, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile a C++ program like this:

```
$ g++ -o Sniffer_Train main.cpp Sniffer_train.cpp Sniffer_train.h -lmysqlclient -lpcap
```

However I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cct6xeXD.o: undefined reference to symbol
'pthread_join@@GLIBC_2.4' //lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0:
error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what this error means. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

DSO here means [Dynamic Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Shared_Object); since the error message says it's missing from the command line, I guess you have to add it to the command line.

That is, try adding `-lpthread` to your command line.

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem with some other project and was able to solve it this way. I just want to add that now that I looked closer I can see that the error is actually very unambigious on what the problem is. I mean, it does say that `pthread_join` is undefined and that it belongs to `libpthread.so`. But like srai I had no idea what the error meant until I came here. :-)

Comment: Does the error show that the ld know the needed DSO is `//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0`?