# Linking error: DSO missing from command line

Tags: linux, linker, x11, glfw, nvcc

I am rather new to Linux (using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit), coming from Windows, and am attempting to port over an existing CUDA project of mine.

When linking via

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -arch=compute_30 -code=sm_30,compute_30 -o Main.o Display.o FileUtil.o Timer.o NeuralNetwork.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lGLU -lcuda -lcudart
```

I encounter the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_clipboard.c.o): undefined reference to  symbol 'XConvertSelection'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CUDANN] Error 1
```

The answer seems closely related to the solutions in this post ([Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)), though given my inexperience with Linux I was unable to adapt them to my own problem.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Here is the full output during compilation: https://gist.github.com/wbolden/857eddd11e4dcb915c02

And here is my attempt at a Makefile:
https://gist.github.com/wbolden/135033daae04ed0d8cf3

Comment: The linker is telling you exactly what the problem is, and the answer you linked to tells you exactly what to do to fix it. You are clearly running on a platform that disallows indirect linking. Add the library dependencies for the required additional libraries (hint libX11 is shown right in the linker error message). I am removing the CUDA tag from this question, it has nothing to do with CUDA or CUDA programming.

Comment: As I said, I am rather new to Linux (I've only been working with it for a few days), so what might be clear to someone with even moderate experience is not all that clear to me. Using ldd I get the following https://gist.github.com/WilliamHBolden/51a8721b4f8d89df2cef though I don't understand what to do with it. I tried adding -L/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu and -L/lib64 but that did not change the error.

Comment: Maybe you must leave gist or use other system because now gist are not available

Comment: My username changed, replace WilliamHBolden with wbolden

Comment: Also see [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19901934), [DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24096807), and [Linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24989432).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hopefully this will be of help to those, like me, who are new to Linux and don't find anything related to Linux to be particularly obvious.

As noted by talonmies, I am not able to link indirectly and as such need to specify any additional libraries required by the libraries I am using. That is to say, if I link library A, which requires libraries B and C, I need to link all three libraries for the program to link correctly.

To find what other libraries were needed I used the `pkg-config` command, for which I found a guide [here](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html). Running `pkg-config --print-requires --print-requires-private glfw3` gave the following output, which is the list of packages required by glfw3.

```
x11
xrandr
xi
xxf86vm
gl
```

I was then able to find what libraries I needed to include by running `pkg-config --libs`, followed by the name of the library. For example, `pkg-config --libs x11` yielded `-lX11`.

Note: you can pass multiple items to `pkg-config` as input, so running

```
pkg-config --libs $(pkg-config --print-requires --print-requires-private glfw3)
```

will print out all the additional libraries you need to link (`-lX11 -lXrandr -lXi -lXxf86vm -lGL`).

My program now links successfully, I hope this helpful to anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: very helpful. it is interesting u helped a person after 5 years. tanks man

Comment: brilliant answer!

Answer (score 7):

Your linker need X11 library,You need to specify -lX11 to linker

Try

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -arch=compute_30 -code=sm_30,compute_30 -o Main.o Display.o FileUtil.o Timer.o NeuralNetwork.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lGLU -lcuda -lcudart -lX11
```

Comment: I tried doing this earlier in the day and it unfortunately did not resolve my problem. Here is the new error I got https://gist.github.com/WilliamHBolden/225d2064f844d33d958f

Comment: @will bolden: this answer does solve your problem. Adding the x11 library eliminated the dso error. Now you have unsatisfied dependencies. Add those.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add -pthread at the end of the library list (command line) in the Makefile.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands to fix the issue:

```
FLAGS=-lX11 ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static
make
make install
```

Comment: Would you care to add some more reasoning, what is the error and how this fixes it?