# OpenSSL 1.0.1f and "undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_state@@OPENSSL_1.0.0"

Tags: c++, linker, openssl, dpkg

This morning I updated my OpenSSL version to the 1.0.1f, while compiling the project on which i am currently working i got this OpenSSL error from the linker:

> /usr/bin/ld: janus-dtls.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_state@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I went to find clues on the internet and the only thing i found is that i need to compile the project with -lssl and -lcrypto. 
But the thing is that i allready do :

> ./Makefile:598:JANUS_LIBS = -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lnice -lgthread-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -ljansson -lssl -lcrypto -lsofia-sip-ua

So i guessed i will ask DPKG maybe i'am forgeting something. Here is the answer :

> $ pkg-config --libs openssl

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Which is exactly what i do.

Do anyone already encountered this error and manged to fix it ?

Or maybe am i doing something wrong i can't see ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: Also see [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19901934), [DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24096807), and [Linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24989432).

Answer (score 2):

Symbols requests are made BEFORE linking them, so the order of libs is strict.

If `LibA` has a symbol that `LibB` needs the order will be :

```
gcc mod1.o mod2.o -lLibA  -lLibB
```

Double check that all the libraries in `Makefile` aren't missing.