# Unable to build Janus ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c, openssl, janus

Unable to build Janus https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway in Ubuntu 22.04/

I had openssl 3.0.2 preinstalled in my system.

I built Janus using

```
sh autogen.sh 
./configure --prefix=/opt/janus 
make
```

Got following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: janus-dtls.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_CTX_ctrl@@OPENSSL_3.0.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

I need to build Janus in my Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You need to add more details, such as your `configure` command options and compiler being used.  And doesn't Ubuntu have Janus packages you can just install?

Comment: I build janus using

sh autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/opt/janus
make

and in running make I got the error

Comment: Building a project rather than coding is arguably off-topic here.  You may be better off with the Janus Community support: https://janus.discourse.group/

Comment: When asked to add information, you should update the question rather then providing the information in a comment.  That is how SO works, it is not a discussion forum, and as you can see your formatting options are limited in comments.  Your formatting was in any case incorrect in the question.  Fixed.

Comment: Possibly also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551310/openssl-1-0-1f-and-undefined-reference-to-symbol-ssl-stateopenssl-1-0-0  (see also the links in the comments to that question).

Comment: `make`'s output will also contain the build command that is responsible for those error messages.  Probably a `gcc` command immediately preceding.  That would be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the `DSO missing` (*Dynamic linker*), you need to add this to your build commands `-lpthread`.

For the `undefined reference`, it's either you completely forgot to add OpenSSL lib to your linking command, or the order is not correct.