# "DSO missing from command line" in libX11

Tags: linker-errors

While compiling this file

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o qjoypad 
    axis.o axis_edit.o axisw.o button.o button_edit.o buttonw.o event.o flash.o icon.o joypad.o joypadw.o joyslider.o keycode.o layout.o layout_edit.o main.o quickset.o getkey.o moc_axis.o moc_axis_edit.o moc_button.o moc_button_edit.o moc_flash.o moc_icon.o moc_joypad.o moc_joypadw.o moc_keycode.o moc_layout.o moc_getkey.o moc_layout_edit.o    
    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lXtst -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lXtst
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: keycode.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XKeycodeToKeysym'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

However, the symbol is just a global variable:

```
$ readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 | grep XKeycode
     259: 000000000008a000   646 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 XKeycodeToKeysym
    1308: 0000000000029830    73 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _XKeycodeToKeysym
```

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line), but the user was just linking in the wrong place, or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989432/linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line), which is related to `pkgconfig`. As far as I can see, my build command should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. I had to specifically include `-lX11`, which the `.configure` command didn't do, for some reason.

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o qjoypad 
    axis.o axis_edit.o axisw.o button.o button_edit.o buttonw.o event.o flash.o icon.o joypad.o joypadw.o joyslider.o keycode.o layout.o layout_edit.o main.o quickset.o getkey.o moc_axis.o moc_axis_edit.o moc_button.o moc_button_edit.o moc_flash.o moc_icon.o moc_joypad.o moc_joypadw.o moc_keycode.o moc_layout.o moc_getkey.o moc_layout_edit.o    
    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lXtst -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lX11
```

Comment: How exactly...?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Makefile for the bit that says

```
LIBS = -lfoo -lbar ...
```

and add it there.