# How to include gtkmm into eclipse C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, libraries, gtkmm

I've been at this for around 30 minutes now and I just can't wrap my head around how to include gtkmm libraries into your C++ project in eclipse.

I've added the include paths for like every directory in my usr/include/ directory. I think I need to do something involving a linker but I'm not sure what or how.

```
pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags -pthread -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz
```

I did these 2 commands after following a brief reply on here and I'm not sure what to do with this information. Do I need to manually add each directory into my include directories or linker? I've been struggling for ages with this.

Any insight into what EXACTLY to do would be great.

Comment: usually those commands are included to compiler commandline using backquotes `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`

Comment: @tp1 - Yeah, I did them in terminal for simplicity. I just don't know how to actually use C++ libraries. It's surprisingly difficult.

Comment: After a little while I finally think I got it working but now eclipse is telling me every include is an unresolved include yet things like <iostream> work. I thought I had it then Gtk::button couldn't be found. 

Here's the new error:
http://i.imgur.com/M3KyfXO.png

Comment: If you look at the command just after the error in your screenshot, it is telling you that it is missing DSO. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line. Also, providing a code example would be nice for others to test their answer.