# What could cause 'DSO missing from command line' when compiling with wxSQLite3?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm testing a simple `wxSQLite3 open db` app in Linux, with `wxWidgets`, `Code::Blocks`, `SQLite3`.

My build log is:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in db_Connect_GUI (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/lib -c /home/sid/Documents/wxW_Projs/db_Connect_GUI/db_Connect_GUIMain.cpp -o obj/Debug/db_Connect_GUIMain.o
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o bin/Debug/db_Connect_GUI obj/Debug/db_Connect_GUIApp.o obj/Debug/db_Connect_GUIMain.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0  -lsqlite3 -lcurl  /usr/local/lib/libwxcode_gtk3u_wxsqlite3-3.0.a
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libwxcode_gtk3u_wxsqlite3-3.0.a(wxsqlite3.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZNK7wxRegEx7MatchesERK8wxStringi@@WXU_3.0'
    //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

What symbol might be missing from the command line?

Comment: Possibly related: [DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line?rq=1)

Possible duplicate of: [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Comment: I think the regex is missing/failing.  an app with only:   `#include "wx/regex.h"` and `wxRegEx foo("Test");`  fails to compile.

Comment: Adding the `/usr/include/lib/libwxregexu-3.0.a` to the link libraries, and  `#include "wx/regex.h"` let the test compile.  But the original wxSQLite3 db open code has the original problem with library and regex header added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)