# undefined reference to symbol 'socket@@GLIBC_2.4'

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, glibc, libc

I'm new to Linux and cross compilation. I am facing problems in cross-compiling my project.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: build/backchannel-support.o: undefined reference to symbol 'socket@@GLIBC_2.4'
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Can someone please help me here.

Thx-

Comment: Please show your compile and link commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

I hope your are cross compiling this using makefile :
please check the macros like CC LD make sure are are small cc and ld when define seperately see below

```
COMPILER ?= ${CC}
LINKER   ?= ${CC}

cc = $(COMPILER)   # if you keep CC here the make file will confuse
ld = $(LINKER)
```