# Porting App from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.3 getting " DSO missing from command line"

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-14.04, qt4.8, qt5.3

I built this project on qt 4.8 ubuntu 12.04(working) and now building it on qt 5.3 ubuntu 14.04 . I am getting following error while compiling

```
 error: mainwindow.o: undefined reference to symbol     
 '_ZN12QtConcurrent16ThreadEngineBase16setProgressValueEi'
 error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4:
```

.pro file

```
QT += serialport
 QT += widgets
 QT += network
 QT += core
 ...
 ...
 LIBS += "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqjson.so.0"
```

no Idea what to do .. has any one came across this problem before.

Comment: Do you have `concurrent` in the list of `QT` modules?

Comment: I have used qConcurrent in project.

Comment: Thanks Mat .. added QT += concurrent  and it compiled just fine..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)