# DSO Missing from command line error

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, cmake, libxml2

I tried to compile CMakeLists.txt for my project through KDevelop.

This is the output in KDevelop

```
/home/gopichand/Desktop/subsurface/build> make -j2
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/gopichand/Desktop/subsurface/build
[  1%] [  2%] Automoc for target TestProfile
Automoc for target subsurface_corelib
[  2%] [  2%] Built target TestProfile_automoc
Built target subsurface_corelib_automoc
[  3%] Automoc for target TestUnitConversion
[  3%] Built target version
[  3%] Built target TestUnitConversion_automoc
[  3%] Built target link_marble_data
[  4%] Automoc for target subsurface
[  5%] Automoc for target subsurface_profile
[  5%] Built target subsurface_automoc
[  5%] Built target subsurface_profile_automoc
[  6%] Automoc for target subsurface_generated_ui
[  7%] Automoc for target subsurface_interface
[  7%] Built target subsurface_generated_ui_automoc
[  8%] [  8%] Built target subsurface_interface_automoc
Automoc for target subsurface_statistics
AUTOMOC: warning: /home/gopichand/Desktop/subsurface/qt-ui/statistics/yearstatistics.cpp: file is empty

AUTOMOC: warning: /home/gopichand/Desktop/subsurface/qt-ui/statistics/statisticsbar.cpp: file is empty

AUTOMOC: warning: /home/gopichand/Desktop/subsurface/qt-ui/statistics/monthstatistics.cpp: file is empty

[  8%] Built target subsurface_statistics_automoc
[ 26%] Built target subsurface_generated_ui
Scanning dependencies of target subsurface_corelib
[ 27%] Building C object CMakeFiles/subsurface_corelib.dir/save-git.c.o
[ 38%] Built target subsurface_profile
[ 39%] Building C object CMakeFiles/subsurface_corelib.dir/subsurfacestartup.c.o
Scanning dependencies of target subsurface_interface
[ 39%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/subsurface_interface.dir/qt-ui/updatemanager.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libsubsurface_corelib.a
[ 64%] Built target subsurface_corelib
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/subsurface_interface.dir/qt-ui/about.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/subsurface_interface.dir/qt-ui/mainwindow.cpp.o
[ 70%] Built target subsurface_statistics
[ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/subsurface_interface.dir/qt-ui/usersurvey.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable TestProfile
/usr/bin/ld: libsubsurface_corelib.a(parse-xml.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'xmlCheckVersion@@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [TestProfile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestProfile.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX static library libsubsurface_interface.a
[ 93%] Built target subsurface_interface
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Failure: Exit code 2 ***
```

I searched all DSO related posts, but could not get what went wrong.

This is the CMakeLists.txt file I compiled using KDevelop.

```
project(Subsurface)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#options
SET(SUBSURFACE_QT_VERSION "4")

SET(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
SET(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/marbledata)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUXX)
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu99 ")
endif()

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( . ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} qt-ui qt-ui/profile)
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig)

MACRO(pkg_config_library LIBNAME pcfile)
    pkg_check_modules(${LIBNAME} ${pcfile})
    include_directories(${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${${LIBNAME}_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_definitions(${${LIBNAME}_CFLAGS_OTHER})
    set(SUBSURFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${SUBSURFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES} ${${LIBNAME}_LIBRARIES})
ENDMACRO()

pkg_config_library(LIBXML libxml-2.0)
pkg_config_library(LIBSQLITE3 sqlite3)
pkg_config_library(LIBGIT2 libgit2)
pkg_config_library(LIBXSLT libxslt)

SET(LIBDCDEVEL "" CACHE STRING "libraries")
IF(NOT (LIBDCDEVEL STREQUAL ""))
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 OLD)
    include_directories(${LIBDCDEVEL}/include )
    link_directories(${LIBDCDEVEL}/src/.libs)
ENDIF()

STRING(COMPARE EQUAL "${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}" "${${PROJECT_NAME}_BINARY_DIR}" insource)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(PARENTDIR ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR} PATH)
STRING(COMPARE EQUAL "${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}" "${PARENTDIR}" insourcesubdir)
IF(NOT (insource OR insourcedir))
    add_custom_target(link_marble_data ALL COMMAND rm -f marbledata && ln -s ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/marbledata ${${PROJECT_NAME}_BINARY_DIR}/marbledata)
ENDIF()

#configure Qt version.
IF(${SUBSURFACE_QT_VERSION} MATCHES "4")
    SET(QT_USE_QTNETWORK TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTSVG TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTTEST TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTWEBKIT TRUE)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
    INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
    FIND_PACKAGE(Marble REQUIRED)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MARBLE_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSEIF(${SUBSURFACE_QT_VERSION} MATCHES "5")
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DNO_MARBLE)
ELSE()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Qt version should be 4 or 5" )
ENDIF()

# Generate the ssrf-config.h every 'make'
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.h.in "\#define VERSION_STRING \"4.1.\"@VERSION@\n")
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.cmake "EXECUTE_PROCESS(
    COMMAND date +\"%s\"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE VERSION
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
 )
 CONFIGURE_FILE(\${SRC} \${DST} @ONLY)
")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(version ALL COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D SRC=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.h.in
                     -D DST=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ssrf-version.h
                     -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/version.cmake
)

# compile the core library, in C.
SET(SUBSURFACE_CORE_LIB_SRCS
    cochran.c
    deco.c
    device.c
    dive.c
    divelist.c
    equipment.c
    file.c
    libdivecomputer.c
    load-git.c
    membuffer.c
    parse-xml.c
    planner.c
    profile.c
    gaspressures.c
    worldmap-save.c
    save-git.c
    save-xml.c
    save-html.c
    sha1.c
    statistics.c
    strtod.c
    subsurfacestartup.c
    time.c
    uemis.c
    uemis-downloader.c
    linux.c
    #gettextfrommoc should be added because we are using it on the c-code.
    gettextfromc.cpp
    #dirk ported some core functionality to c++.
    qthelper.cpp
    divecomputer.cpp
    exif.cpp
    subsurfacesysinfo.cpp
    devicedetails.cpp
    configuredivecomputer.cpp
    configuredivecomputerthreads.cpp
)

#the interface, in C++
SET(SUBSURFACE_INTERFACE
    qt-ui/updatemanager.cpp
    qt-ui/about.cpp
    qt-ui/completionmodels.cpp
    qt-ui/divecomputermanagementdialog.cpp
    qt-ui/divelistview.cpp
    qt-ui/diveplanner.cpp
    qt-ui/diveshareexportdialog.cpp
    qt-ui/downloadfromdivecomputer.cpp
    qt-ui/globe.cpp
    qt-ui/graphicsview-common.cpp
    qt-ui/kmessagewidget.cpp
    qt-ui/maintab.cpp
    qt-ui/mainwindow.cpp
    qt-ui/modeldelegates.cpp
    qt-ui/models.cpp
    qt-ui/metrics.cpp
    qt-ui/preferences.cpp
    qt-ui/printdialog.cpp
    qt-ui/printlayout.cpp
    qt-ui/printoptions.cpp
    qt-ui/simplewidgets.cpp
    qt-ui/starwidget.cpp
    qt-ui/subsurfacewebservices.cpp
    qt-ui/tableview.cpp
    qt-ui/divelogimportdialog.cpp
    qt-ui/tagwidget.cpp
    qt-ui/groupedlineedit.cpp
    qt-ui/usermanual.cpp
    qt-ui/divelogexportdialog.cpp
    qt-ui/divepicturewidget.cpp
    qt-ui/usersurvey.cpp
    qt-ui/configuredivecomputerdialog.cpp
)

#the profile widget
SET(SUBSURFACE_PROFILE_LIB_SRCS
    qt-ui/profile/profilewidget2.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/diverectitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/divepixmapitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/divelineitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/divetextitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/animationfunctions.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/divecartesianaxis.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/diveplotdatamodel.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/diveprofileitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/diveeventitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/divetooltipitem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/ruleritem.cpp
    qt-ui/profile/tankitem.cpp
)

#the yearly statistics widget.
SET(SUBSURFACE_STATISTICS_LIB_SRCS
    qt-ui/statistics/statisticswidget.cpp
    qt-ui/statistics/yearstatistics.cpp
    qt-ui/statistics/statisticsbar.cpp
    qt-ui/statistics/monthstatistics.cpp
)

#the main app.
SET(SUBSURFACE_APP
    main.cpp
    qt-gui.cpp
    qthelper.cpp
)

FILE(GLOB SUBSURFACE_UI qt-ui/*.ui)
# to be replaced by QT_WRAP_UI on CMake 3.
IF(${SUBSURFACE_QT_VERSION} MATCHES "4")
    QT4_WRAP_UI( SUBSURFACE_UI_HDRS ${SUBSURFACE_UI} )
    QT4_ADD_RESOURCES( SUBSURFACE_QRC_HRDS subsurface.qrc )
ELSEIF(${SUBSURFACE_QT_VERSION} MATCHES "5")
    QT5_WRAP_UI( SUBSURFACE_UI_HDRS ${SUBSURFACE_UI} )
ENDIF()

ADD_LIBRARY(subsurface_corelib STATIC ${SUBSURFACE_CORE_LIB_SRCS} )
ADD_LIBRARY(subsurface_profile STATIC ${SUBSURFACE_PROFILE_LIB_SRCS})
ADD_LIBRARY(subsurface_statistics STATIC ${SUBSURFACE_STATISTICS_LIB_SRCS})
ADD_LIBRARY(subsurface_generated_ui STATIC ${SUBSURFACE_UI_HDRS})
ADD_LIBRARY(subsurface_interface STATIC ${SUBSURFACE_INTERFACE})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(subsurface ${SUBSURFACE_APP} ${SUBSURFACE_QRC_HRDS} )

target_link_libraries( subsurface
  subsurface_generated_ui
  subsurface_interface
  subsurface_profile
  subsurface_statistics
  subsurface_corelib
  ${QT_LIBRARIES}
  ${MARBLE_LIBRARIES}
  ${SUBSURFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES}
  -ldivecomputer
  -lzip
)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(subsurface_statistics subsurface_generated_ui)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(subsurface_profile subsurface_generated_ui)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(subsurface_interface subsurface_generated_ui)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(subsurface_generated_ui version)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(subsurface_corelib version)

ENABLE_TESTING()
ADD_EXECUTABLE( TestUnitConversion tests/testunitconversion.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( TestUnitConversion ${QT_LIBRARIES}  ${SUBSURFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES} -lzip -ldivecomputer subsurface_corelib)
ADD_TEST( NAME TestUnitConversion COMMAND TestUnitConversion)

ADD_EXECUTABLE( TestProfile tests/testprofile.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( TestProfile ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${SUBSURFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES} -lzip -ldivecomputer subsurface_corelib)
ADD_TEST( NAME TestProfile COMMAND TestProfile)
```

Can someone please help me with this... :)

Comment: Have you searched for `DSO missing from command line`? Did you find the results unsatisfactory? Why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CMake,so could not figure out what's wrong with this. All that I need is to fix this problem and go back to work on the project.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: libsubsurface_corelib.a(parse-xml.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'xmlCheckVersion@@LIBXML2_2.4.30'   , your library is most probably wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)