# Undefined reference to curlpp using code::blocks on kubuntu

Tags: c++, include-path, curlpp

I have a problem with curlpp library. I'll explain the steps that I followed.

---

### Step 1: download and installation

download website: [Download](https://code.google.com/p/curlpp/downloads/detail?name=curlpp-0.7.3.tar.gz&can=2&q=)

```
$./configure
$make
$sudo make install
```

- curlpp header files are located in  **/usr/local/include/**
- curlpp library files are located in **/usr/local/lib/**

---

### Step 2: I used the following code:

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *url = (char*) "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";

    string queryString = "PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> "
        "PREFIX dbp2: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> "
        "SELECT ?abstract "
        "WHERE { "
            "dbp:Nikola_Tesla dbp2:abstract ?abstract . "
            "FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract), 'en')"
        "}";

    try
    {
        curlpp::Easy request;
        string parameters = "query=" + curlpp::escape(queryString);

        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(url));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Verbose(true));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(parameters));

        request.perform();
    }

    catch (curlpp::RuntimeError & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    catch (curlpp::LogicError & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}//end function main
```

---

**Errors**

- Undefined reference to curlpp **::Easy:Easy()**
- Undefined reference to curlpp **::escape (const std :: string &)**
- Undefined reference to curlpp **::Easy::setopt (curlpp OptionBase :: *)**
- Undefined reference to curlpp **curlpp::Easy::setopt(curlpp OptionBase:: *)**
- etc.

---

After adding -lcurlpp as the picture shows: I got the following errors:
[image: picture 1]

> g++ -LSQLiteCpp-master/debug -o bin/Debug/EntityLinking
>   obj/Debug/DataLoader.o obj/Debug/Entity.o obj/Debug/Fact.o
>   obj/Debug/FactClass.o obj/Debug/Link.o obj/Debug/main.o
>   obj/Debug/ManageDb.o obj/Debug/SQLiteCpp-master/sqlite3/sqlite3.o
>   obj/Debug/tinyxml/tinystr.o obj/Debug/tinyxml/tinyxml.o
>   obj/Debug/tinyxml/tinyxmlerror.o obj/Debug/tinyxml/tinyxmlparser.o 
>   -lpthread -ldl -lcurlpp  SQLiteCpp-master/debug/libSQLiteCpp.a /usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/main.o: référence au symbole non défini
>   «curl_easy_setopt@@CURL_OPENSSL_3»
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: error adding symbols: DSO
>   missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 0
>   error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: have you tried curl-config --libs, or pkg-config --libs curl on the command line? Or have you tried to add -lssl as a linker flag?

Comment: I added -lcurl witth -lcurlpp to the **other linking options** it actually solved the problem but I don't know why and how to explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with `-lcurlpp` when compiling & linking your code.

Comment: When I add `-lcurlpp` in other link options. I get the following error: Error adding symbols:DSO missing from command line

Comment: try putting it in the end of the link command. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line) out.

Comment: @Amon I added a picture can you check it please i'll check the link that you posted i was just adding it

Comment: I actually added just `-lcurl` along side `-lcurlpp` and it worked don't really know why. Thanks for your help

Comment: make sure you install libcurlpp-dev with this command ->      
     sudo apt install libcurlpp-dev

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse, I never got curlpp example01 working. Even after trying to set up the linkers and the includes. But I was able to compile it from a terminal:

```
g++ -o exe_name exe_name.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl -lcurlpp -I/usr/local/include
```

So I would suggest trying the terminal if Eclipse doesn't work for you.