# undefined __expf_finite@@GLIBC_2.15, libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, dynamic-linking

I am trying to compile something for the last day and it is not working at all. following is my g++ command:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -march=native -mfpmath=sse -fopenmp  -fno-trapping-math -fsingle-precision-constant -funroll-loops -g -I../../include/  `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -Wl,--start-group  ../../lib/libmoped.a -lm  -lm `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lgomp -lGLEW -lglut -lIL -lm camera.cpp -o camera
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libmoped.a(ProgramGPU.o): undefined reference to symbol '__expf_finite@@GLIBC_2.15'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I tried adding -lm multiple times, in the beginning, in the end as well as several times after each of the libraries to resolve circular dependency, but still I get the same error. I tried --start-group and put everything inside as shown in the provided command, and still end up getting the same error with the error. What is wrong?

Comment: Which version of glibc do you have installed?

Comment: it looks like a linking problem.. Did you check your link?

Comment: @Wintermute, I am using g++/gcc 4.6

Comment: @goGud, checking link of what? I don't have a binary built yet.

Comment: That's good to know, but which version of glibc? If it's older than 2.15, that would be important to know.

Comment: @Wintermute, it is 2.19 I just found out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)