# Dynamically linking from a static libarary?

Tags: linux, static-libraries, ld

I'm currently attempting to rebuild FlightGear on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Everything went smoothly until I decided to build `fgrun` which requires Qt. I decided to compile Qt as a static library since I didn't want self-built libraries overrunning any on the system.

I statically built Qt on the system like so:

```
./configure -static -opensource -nomake tests -gtkstyle -prefix /home/user/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbuild -no-rpath -no-compile-examples -system-proxies -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples -nomake tools -nomake examples -skip script -release -skip multimedia -verbose -l dl -skip location -skip multimedia -skip quick1 -skip quickcontrols -skip sensors -skip serialport -skip svg -skip tools -skip translations -skip wayland -skip webchannel -skip webengine -skip xmlpatterns -skip activeqt -skip connectivity -skip declarative -skip doc -skip enginio -skip graphicaleffects -skip imageformats -skip websockets
```

I showed FlightGear's CMake where to find the libraries and everything appeared fine until the final linking stage:

```
Linking CXX executable fgfs
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Qt/5.4/Src/qtbuild/lib/libQt5Core.a(qlibrary_unix.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now, I've run into this issue before and it was a matter of not linking the the dynamic linker library via `-ldl`. However, I've ensured that both Qt and FlightGear are built with the `-ldl` flag, yet I still get this error.

So now, this begs the question in my mind: is it even possible to dynamically link from a static library? I would imagine that -ldl would have to be included in the static library which would be a Bad Idea, is this correct?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line) suggests that you might've placed the `-ldl` flag in the wrong place.

Comment: Qt doesn't give me an options as to where to place -ldl (this is the -l option of the configure), nor to I understand the tangled mess that is the Qt source >.>. I'm trying to locate it in order to see if there's a better place to put it, but no luck so far. I was fairly easily able to change its placement in FlightGear (just in case) and was left with a a flood of errors about almost every other external library call being undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says you're missing `dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5` which is part of glibc (the GNU C Library used by GCC). This symbol is part of `dl.so` which maps to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2` on my system.

When you add it to the build, make sure `-ldl` is at the end of the command. The linker will collect missing symbols as it processes libraries but it will process each library exactly once. So you need to be sure that `-dl` is after the library which needs it.

> is it even possible to dynamically link from a static library?

Yes. A static library is added to your code as if it was part of your own source, i.e. library is just a bunch of compiled object (`*.o`) files. The function names are the key to look up the object files. You could also unpack the library and write:

```
gcc -o exe main.o qtfoo.o -ldl
```

where `qtfoo.o` is an entry from `libQt5Core.a`

Another solution is to build Qt with dynamic loading and install it into `$HOME/local/`. The build setup should allow to specify the install folder.

When you build FlightGear, you can pass `$HOME/local/lib` as additional folder for shared libraries. To start FlightGear, you need to set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If you do this in a start script, only FlightGear will be able to see/use your own version of Qt.

Comment: FlightGear uses CMake, which I'm not too familiar with, but I found the .txt file that is the linking command and added -ldl to the end of it (after libQtCore.a as you suggested) and I got a flood of errors to a slew of suddenly undefined symbols that weren't there before. As I was writing this I tried it again and it suddenly worked. Well, thanks for the answer though I have no idea how or why it worked this time and not the last time!

Comment: `dl.so` needs some other stuff (not much, though). So make sure it's one of the last `-l` options that you pass. The order of `-L` (path) options is not important; you should just have them before the first `-l`.

Comment: I reset my Qt and FlightGear builds and just added the -ldl in the FlightGear cmake nonsense and I got the same errors I described in the comment to my question. So, that alone didn't fix it. In my haste to get it built I started throwing `-ldl` a lot of places it probably shouldn't have been and some combination worked -- now I'm tediously going through and trying to figure out which one did it. The cleaning process for the Qt base package takes like 15 minutes each time though...

Comment: Alright, so I think my initial successful build was an accident -- I had forgot to tell CMake where I had put Qt and it continued without out. I finally got it going, but it turns out I have to link every single library that Qt links to, which is quite a few to say the least but after all that hassle it's working like a charm.