# SamDump2-3.0.0 build fails DSO missing from command line

Tags: linux, compiler-errors

I downloaded the source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ophcrack/files/samdump2/3.0.0/) after extracting and entering the folder I ran the make command and get the out put:

```
    /usr/bin/gcc -Wall -c -o hive.o hive.c
    /usr/bin/gcc -Wall -c -o list.o list.c
    /usr/bin/gcc -Wall -c -o bkhive.o bkhive.c
    /usr/bin/gcc -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
    /usr/bin/gcc -Wall -c -o dumpsam.o dumpsam.c
    Building binary...
    /usr/bin/gcc -o samdump2 hive.o list.o bkhive.o samdump.o main.o dumpsam.o -Wall -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld samdump.o: undefined reference to symbol 'DES_ecb_encrypt'
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:41: recipe for target 'samdump2' failed
    make: *** [samdump2] Error 1
```

I am running Arch linux 64 bit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with `LDFLAGS="-lcrypto $LDFLAGS" make`

Comment: Doesn't change any although I might be doing it wrong. How exactly do I do this? Sorry I am new at this.

Comment: Fixed by adding -lcrypto to CFLAGS in the Makefile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)