# FlannBasedMatcher matcher building

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

as soon as i add to my code

```
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
```

i get the following error when building

> g++  -o "track"  ./track.o   -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d
>   -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video /usr/bin/ld: ./track.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   '_ZN2cv5flann12SearchParamsC1Eifb'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so.2.4: error adding
>   symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

any idea? I am running Ubuntu

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from an earlier question ([Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line))

> You should mention the library on the command line after the object
>   files being compiled

So, in your case:

1. Find out where _ZN2cv5flann12SearchParamsC1Eifb (actually "cv::flann::SearchParams::SearchParams(int, float, bool)") is defined:

> nm -AD  --defined-only /usr/lib64/libopencv_*so.* | grep
>   _ZN2cv5flann12SearchParamsC1Eifb /usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.2.4:0000000000029650 T
>   _ZN2cv5flann12SearchParamsC1Eifb /usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.9:0000000000029650 T
>   _ZN2cv5flann12SearchParamsC1Eifb

2. add -lopencv_flann to the link command immediately after it was referenced:

> g++     fbm.cc   -o fbm -lopencv_flann -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video

Code sample for testing:

```
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

int main()
{}
```