# libstdc++: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, makefile, gtkmm

I am having trouble implementing a gtkmm application's makefile. I have implemented a simple solution, however, I am getting the following error:

> g++ -Wall -std=c++11 `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` -c main.cpp
>
> cc   main.o  `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs` -o main
>
> /usr/bin/ld: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3'
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> : recipe for target 'main' failed
>
> make: *** [main] Error 1

Makefile:

```
# Compiler
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags`

# gtkmm library flags
LDLIBS = `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`

PROGRAM = main
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPEND = .depend

.PHONY: clean

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

# Object file rules:
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

# Dependencies
.depend:
    rm -f ./.depend
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $(SRCS) > $(DEPEND)

all: .depend $(PROGRAM)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm -f $(PROGRAM)
    rm -f $(DEPEND)

-include $(DEPEND)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

#include "MainWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  MainWindow window;

  // Show windows and return when closed
  return app->run(window);
}
```

MainWindow.hpp:

```
#ifndef GUI_MAIN_WINDOW_H
#define GUI_MAIN_WINDOW_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow: public Gtk::Window {

  public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

  protected:
    Gtk::Frame frame;

};

#endif // GUI_MAIN_WINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow() {
  // Set window properties
  set_title("Main window");
  set_size_request(300, 300);

  // Set window border width
  set_border_width(10);

  // Add frame
  add(frame);

  // Set frame's label
  frame.set_label("Frame");

  // Align the label at the right of the frame
  frame.set_label_align(Gtk::ALIGN_END, Gtk::ALIGN_START);

  // Set the style of the frame
  frame.set_shadow_type(Gtk::SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);

  show_all_children();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  // Nothing to do here
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how about linking against `libstdc++` by adding `-L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++`?

Comment: Linker error, have you tried to compile manually ? Try to specify libstdc++.so.6 at the end of the command.

Comment: Link with g++ not gcc. Do not manually add libstdc++ to the command line. Just link with g++.

Comment: @n.m. Am I not using g++ in the makefile?

Comment: Look at the resulting link command. `cc main.o ...`. This should use g++, not cc.

Comment: Apparently you attempt to use g++ but there's a misspelling in the rule (PROG vs PROGRAM).

Comment: Wow, that was a stupid mistake. Thank you! Solved.

Comment: Why does it default to using cc otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Answer (score 33):

I met the same issue when built openCV libraries

```
$ gcc DisplayImage.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` -o DisplayImage
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbyJ7Ms.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**[SOLVE]**

For **gcc** try adding `-lstdc++` to your command.

```
$ gcc DisplayImage.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` -o DisplayImage -lstdc++
```

For **g++** it will link **libstdc.so.6++** automatically

```
$ g++ DisplayImage.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags` -o DisplayImage
```

Comment: helpfull for me , thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem it was solved by addiing -lstdc++ in command line.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, in my case the problem was writing `gcc` instead of `g++`

Comment: For me it was clang++ instead of clang. Similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when compiling zeromq (zmq) into my project. Adding **-lstdc++** to the link line in my makefile solved the problem.