# Compile RGBdemo: Error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to install RGBdemo in linux mint, I have installed previous libraries and packages. When I run sudo make install I get the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glOrtho'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/Sample-Players] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nestk/deps/openni/Nite/Samples/Players/CMakeFiles/Sample-Players.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Any suggestion?? I'm not a programmer and really I have a poor background in programming

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I turned off OpenNi Flags and install an old version (0.5), and it runs perfectly fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)