# DSO missing from command line opencv

Tags: opencv, g++

I ran this command

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binary DisplayImage.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_stitching
```

I am getting this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccB73ml3.o: undefined reference to symbol
'_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'

//usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0: error adding symbols: DSO
missing from command line
```

I dont know what order it should be the linking

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Comment: I read but I dont understand how will it help in my execution command. I mean what should I change in my command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)