# DSO missing from command line Compiling TrueCrypt

Tags: gcc, debian, wxwidgets, dynamic-linking, truecrypt

I've been trying to compile `truecrypt 7.1a` on Debian Jessie 8.1.0 AMD64 for the past two days now.  I have `wxGTK2.8.12` source because Debian Jessie only have v3.0 packages. That's a problem because `wxwidgets3.0` has protected `wxstandardpaths` so you have to use `wxstandardpaths::get` and `truecrypt` uses `wxstandardpaths` in `application.cpp` for example and it would return an error while compiling.

I'm not sure how to fix that so I went to option 2 compile `wxgtk2.8.12` source using the truecrypt compile option `# make WX_ROOT=/usr/src/truecrypt-7.1a-source/wxGTK-2.8.12 wxbuild.` That completes then I do `# make WXSTATIC=1` and I run into this error below. Even if I compile and install `wxwidgets-2.8.12` myself I get this error. Maybe it's a `x11lib` issue?

^
Linking truecrypt

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld:
> /usr/src/truecrypt-7.1a-source/wxrelease/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.a(corelib_utilsx11.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
> //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO
> missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> Main.make:107: recipe for target 'truecrypt' failed make[1]: ***
> [truecrypt] Error 1 Makefile:268: recipe for target 'all' failed make:
> *** [all] Error 2
> ```

Comment: Adding `-lX11` to your link command line should fix this error.

Comment: it says -lx11 command not found ive tried to do it before i also tried LIBS=-lx11 that goes thru but does nothing.

Comment: VZ. root@User:/usr/src/truecrypt-7.1a-source# -lX11
bash: -lX11: command not found
  ive tried to do it before and it hasnt worked what do you mean by link command line? Did i do it wrong? i've typed LIBS=-lx11 that goes thru but does nothing.

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same issue. Did you found a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)