# a gcc strange ld error when compile some ffmpeg application, libvorbisenc package not found

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ffmpeg

I follow the [ffmpeg tuorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial02.html), and install ffmpeg via [ppa](https://mintguide.org/video/339-installing-ffmpeg-library-on-linux-mint-via-ppa.html)

But when I compiled the tuorial02.c, I got gcc error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /opt/ffmpeg/lib//libavcodec.a(libvorbisenc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'vorbis_encode_setup_vbr'
>
> //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My compile command is:

```
gcc -I /opt/ffmpeg/include/ -L /opt/ffmpeg/lib/  -o tutorial02 tutorial02.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale `sdl-config --cflags --libs`  -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl
```

I have searched the reason for hours. I can't solve this. Can anyone help me?

**Added** I have add `-lvorbisenc` to the end. the error is lib not found. and libvorivisenc2 has been install. so this question is not a duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

And My OS is Linux mint 17.3

Comment: Try adding `-lvorbisenc` to the end of your compiling/linking command. It looks like the linker is complaining that it can't find `vorbis_encode_setup_vbr`, which is defined in [libvorbisenc](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisenc/vorbis_encode_setup_vbr.html), which suggests you aren't linking to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Comment: @Cornstalks when I add `-lvorbisenc` to the end of my command. and got error /usr/bin/ld:  **cannot find -lvorbisenc**. but package libvorbisenc2 has been installed. And my os is Linux mint 17.3

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the static library `libavcodec.a` references symbols from libvorbisenc but libvorbisenc isn't explicitly in your link command (though it did find a good candidate from another shared library in the link command).  You'll need to add `-lvorbisenc` or `$(pkg-config --libs vorbisenc)` explicitly to your command line.

(Older versions of binutils would let you bring in shared libraries implicitly in this situation; however, newer versions of binutils are stricter.)

Comment: yeah, It may be the reason. but when add `-lvorbisenc`, the error is can't find libvorbisenc. I also can't find the package. when I run `(pkg-config --libs vorbisenc`, the error is: Package vorbisenc was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `vorbisenc.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'vorbisenc' found. and my OS is Linux Mint 17.3 . Thanks

Comment: On my Debian system, `libvorbis-dev` package contains `vorbisenc.pc` so I'd check if `libvorbis-dev` is installed.

Comment: Thank you!! It's libvorbis-dev package contains. but unfortunately, I think i commad is wrong, There are a lot error, like: /libavcodec.a(libmp3lame.o): In function `mp3lame_encode_init':
(.text.unlikely+0x169): undefined reference to `lame_init_params'
.           the ffmpeg's lib is static lib. is that wrong? Sorry to confuse you.

Comment: ffmpeg being a static lib isn't wrong.  However, precisely what you're running into is one of the big disadvantages of static libs vs shared libs: with static libs you have to give all the transitive dependencies explicitly, whereas with shared libs all you have to specify is the libraries your program uses explicitly.  In this case, you'd have to track down the LAME library (`apt-cache search lame` to find `libmp3lame-dev` in my case), and so on for any other indirect dependencies from ffmpeg.