# ALSA Library and Cross Compiling for ARM

Tags: c, linux, gcc, alsa

I'm trying to make an "C" application for my NXP(Freescale) imx6 that Debian OS installed on it. My host machine is Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using eclipse as an IDE and I can manage to cross compile until today. I use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` as an compiler and `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld`  as an linker. I added `-lasound` option to my linker parameter, but still can not build the application. I get an error

> arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lasound

I think I don't have the `libasound.so` file on my Ubuntu (Host) machine  and my linker couldn't link to library to my application.

I copied the `libasound.so` file from my ARM machine to my host machine to the `/home/user/Downloads` folder, but still couldn't compile.

Is there a step to use ALSA library in Cross Compilation project before build?

Here is the output of build operation

```
Building target: tihc_linux_application
Invoking: GCC C Linker
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -static -L/home/user/Downloads -pthread -lasound -o "main"  ./src/main.o   
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: mode armelf_linux_eabi
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lasound
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for static link (via `-static`) but provide shared library so `ld` probably ignores it (to be sure you can run with `-Wl,--verbose`). One option is to cross-compile libalsa from scratch and then use resulting static lib to link your app. Another option is to search for pre-compiled gnueabihf libalsa somewhere...

Comment: I deleted static flag and added the verbose flag. After these changes, as you mentioned, linker found the shared object file, but this time I got another error.

`//usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`

Comment: @BlackGlix That's [strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line). TLDR - move object file to front of command line, libs to the end.