# caffe libopencv_core DSO missing from command line

Tags: opencv, makefile, caffe

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.3.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.2.4
/usr/bin/ld: .build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:633: recipe for target '.build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin] Error 1
```

I keep getting this error when I compile caffe with make all command.
I added opencv libraries in Makefile and uncommented the part where I set caffe to use opencv3 in Makefile.config. 
I recompiled opencv3 with -D BUILD_TIFF=ON and still nothing.

Comment: you have two versions of opencv installed 3.2 and 2.4 and all are pointed on libopencv_imgcodecs.so symlic,you either have to unink one of them..escpeically if in your caffe Makefile you are using opencv=3 then you have to remove 2.4,good luck

Comment: //usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2 check also if you havent an extra / infront of your opencv include dir

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan I have given up on this and am currently running caffe on a different machine... I'll let you know how fixing goes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem too. You can review the Makefile.config and check if the opencv lib dir in LIBRARY_DIRS. Or Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths. USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1