# /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9zxSDP.o: undefined reference to symbol

Tags: c++, gcc, ignite

The following compile error i am facing when i compile a .cc file. i am using apache ignite libraries and c++ libraries to compile and jdk path is specified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ignite/ignite.h"
#include "ignite/ignition.h"
using namespace ignite;
using namespace cache;

int main()
{
    IgniteConfiguration cfg;
    cfg.jvmInitMem = 512;
    cfg.jvmMaxMem = 512;
    cfg.springCfgPath = "/home/ignite/DataGridTest.xml";
    try
    {
        Ignite grid = Ignition::Start(cfg);

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << ">>> Cache put-get example started." << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        Cache<int, int> cache = grid.GetCache<int, int>("mycache");

        cache.Clear();
        cache.Put(1, 1);
        int orgFromCache = cache.Get(1);

        std::cout <<  ">>> Retrieved value from cache: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << orgFromCache << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        Ignition::StopAll(false);
    }
    catch (IgniteError& err)
    {
        std::cout << "An error occurred: " << err.GetText() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << ">>> Example finished, press 'Enter' to exit ..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In command line:

```
gcc -I /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/ -I 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/linux/ -I 
$IGNITE_HOME/platforms/cpp/jni/include/ -I 
$IGNITE_HOME/platforms/cpp/core/include/ -I 
$IGNITE_HOME/platforms/cpp/common/os/linux/include/ -I 
$IGNITE_HOME/platforms/cpp/examples/include/ DataGridTest.cc -o DataGridTest -lignite

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9zxSDP.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN6ignite3jni4java12JniErrorInfoD1Ev'
/usr/local/lib//libignite-jni-2.0.0.19668.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Move `-lignite` before `DataGridTest.cc`

Comment: i added -lignite-jni and few more .so files i linked related to ignite but, isn't it enough only to give -lignite it would cover all .so files that comes as a part if ignite library.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)? Make sure you are adding libraries after object files.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the `libignite` you also need to link to `libignite-binary`, `libignite-common` and `libignite-jni`.