# GCC undefined reference to HDF5

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, linker, undefined-reference

When compiling IOAPI-3.1, I encountered this error:

```
cd /home/usr/ioapi/Linux2_x86_64gfort; gfortran  /home/usr/ioapi/Linux2_x86_64gfort/airs2m3.o -L/home/usr/ioapi/Linux2_x86_64gfort -lioapi -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -fopenmp -dynamic -L/usr/lib64 -lm -lpthread -lc  -o airs2m3
/usr/bin/ld: /home/usr/ioapi/Linux2_x86_64gfort/libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4file.o): undefined reference to symbol 'H5DSget_num_scales@@HDF5_SERIAL_1.8.7'
/usr/lib/mpich/lib/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'airs2m3' failed
make[1]: *** [airs2m3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/usr/ioapi/m3tools'
Makefile:141: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've read this post which is related to my problem [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line) but I was unable to follow the solutions presented due to my relative inexperience with Linux.

Could you give me ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't link with the HDF5 library.

Static libraries (like the `netcdf` library is) is nothing more than an archive of object files, it's really no different than specifying the object files themselves on the command line. As such, all dependencies of a static library *must* be specified when linking.

Also remember that order matters. If library A depends on library B, then A must come before B on the command line.