# libgtest.so error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, googletest

I have been using gtests for unit testing a personal project. Last week I upgraded to the LTS version of Linux Mint. Unfortunately, after that event, I haven't been able to compile my project due to gtests linking problems.

The following error is being issued:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: build/tests/policies/roundrobin_tests.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7testing4TestC2Ev'
/home/myuser/Documents/googletest-release-1.8.0/googletest/libgtest.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have generated both **libgtest.so** and **libgtest_main.so** through CMake 3.10.2. The gtest version is the release-1.8.0, the same I used to have before.

Those libraries are located in /usr/lib and the corresponding include folder has also been copied to /usr/include. I made sure that this location is in my ld path and that is not the problem.

My compiler is g++ v7.3.0 and the command Im using to compile the testes is:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -O3 -Iinclude build/tests/policies/roundrobin_tests.o -lgtest_main -pthread -o bin/policies/roundrobin_tests
```

I have tried altering the order of the elements in the command, explicitly adding -L/usr/lib and -I/usr/include without luck. A funny fact is that if I take off the -pthread flag, the error is still the same.

The same command was used before and the only difference is the compiler version I am using now as I used g++ 5.4.0 before. Any insights on how to solve this?

**edit:** Just tested the same process with g++ 5.4.0 and CMake 3.5 and the same problems ocurred.

Comment: possible  duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line ?

Comment: @sandwood this question you mentioned does not have a solution to my problem. I mentioned I have tried swapping the parameters without success. Sadly, that probably is not what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing to link lib -lgtest