# How to compile static OpenCV4 libraries?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

For testing purposes, I need to compile my C++ opencv program using static libs. My cmake build options are:

```
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \ 
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF\
    -D FORCE_VTK=OFF \
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF \
    -D WITH_GDAL=OFF \ 
    -D WITH_IPP=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENEXR=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF \ 
    -D WITH_QT=OFF\
    -D WITH_TBB=OFF \ 
    -D WITH_XINE=OFF \ 
    -D BUILD_JPEG=ON  \
    -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
    -D BUILD_PNG=ON \
```

I can see that I have the files in both `/usr/local/libs/ and the headers in /usr/local/include/` .And I have test program to display an image which uses `highgui, core and imgcodec libs` Reading similar questions/threads I tried compiling my program using the following where the build order is critical:

```
    g++ main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/opencv4 -L /usr/local/lib 
    -L /usr/local/share/opencv4 -L /usr/local/lib/opencv4 -lopencv_highgui \
    -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui \
    -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching \
    -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lrt \
    -lz -lpthread -o binary
```

However it just spits out numerous errors like:

```
    usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function `icvOnKeyPress(_GtkWidget*, _GdkEventKey*, void*)':window_gtk.cpp:(.text._ZL13icvOnKeyPressP10_GtkWidgetP12_GdkEventKeyPv+0x98): undefined reference to `g_mutex_lock'
    window_gtk.cpp:(.text._ZL13icvOnKeyPressP10_GtkWidgetP12_GdkEventKeyPv+0xaa): undefined reference to `g_cond_broadcast'
    window_gtk.cpp:(.text._ZL13icvOnKeyPressP10_GtkWidgetP12_GdkEventKeyPv+0xb6): undefined reference to `g_mutex_unlock'/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function `cvImageWidgetSetImage(_CvImageWidget*, void const*)':
    window_gtk.cpp:(.text._Z21cvImageWidgetSetImageP14_CvImageWidgetPKv+0x185): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_get_type' /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clGetExtensionFunctionAddress_switch_fn(char const*)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL49OPENCL_FN_clGetExtensionFunctionAddress_switch_fnPKc+0x33): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL49OPENCL_FN_clGetExtensionFunctionAddress_switch_fnPKc+0x19c): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL49OPENCL_FN_clGetExtensionFunctionAddress_switch_fnPKc+0x1b3): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL49OPENCL_FN_clGetExtensionFunctionAddress_switch_fnPKc+0x296): undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

Apparently using `pkgconfig` has been dropped for [OpenCV4.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13154)
Is there anyway to find the libraries required and the proper order to build using static libraries?

**UPDATE: Now I only have a few errors after fixing the script**
Using the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_photo -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lpng -ljpeg -o binary
```

I only now have:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzeof'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after searching everywhere. I finally did it. I am using docker containers as my working environment. I am using OpenCV 4.0.1 and Ubuntu 18.04. My docker file can be found at [DockerFile](https://github.com/the-black-viper/ubuntucv-local). (The docker image is still built dynamically just follow the steps below to enable static build.)

There are basically two things to do to static compile successfully.

1. `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`

   **AND**
2. `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES`

The second option will save you the hassle of manually linking all libraries during compilation. It is very critical. And to compile I just used the typical:

```
g++ main.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs --static opencv4`
```

Just remember to set the $PKG_CONFIG_PATH to where the opencv4.pc is located.I set mine via:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

You can check it by: `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
I hope this helps anyone struggling to do this!

EDIT: **Dockerfile