# compiling /usr/bin/ld undefined reference to XMapSubwindows and DSO missing from command line

Tags: c, makefile, libraries

I'm trying to compile my patched dwm on Debian.

This is my config.mk file, it's mostly the one from `apt source dwm` but the patches added some extra libraries, and I had to add the two -Ifreetype2 links myself:

```
# dwm version
VERSION = 6.1

# Customize below to fit your system

# paths
PREFIX = /usr/local
MANPREFIX = ${PREFIX}/share/man

# Xinerama, comment if you don't want it
XINERAMALIBS  = -lXinerama
XINERAMAFLAGS = -DXINERAMA

# freetype
FREETYPELIBS = -lfontconfig -lXft
FREETYPEINC = /usr/include/freetype2
# OpenBSD (uncomment)
#FREETYPEINC = ${X11INC}/freetype2

# includes and libs
INCS =  -I${X11INC} -I${FREETYPEINC} -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16
LIBS = -L${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} ${FREETYPELIBS}  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res

# flags
CPPFLAGS += -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=2 -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\" ${XINERAMAFLAGS}
#CFLAGS   = -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -O0 ${INCS} ${CPPFLAGS}
CFLAGS   += -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations ${INCS} ${CPPFLAGS}
LDFLAGS  += -s ${LIBS}

# Solaris
#CFLAGS = -fast ${INCS} -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\"
#LDFLAGS = ${LIBS}

# compiler and linker
CC = cc
```

This is the error I get when running `make clean install`

```
cc -o dwm drw.o dwm.o util.o -s -L -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res
/usr/bin/ld: dwm.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XMapSubwindows'
/usr/bin/ld: //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:29: dwm] Error 1
```

But I have no idea how to fix this. Do I need a library installed? do I need to add somthing to the libs variable? please help!

I have tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/libpthread-so-0-error-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line), but I have no idea what a "DSO" is, nor how to fix the linkage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the only problem but your link line...

```
cc -o dwm drw.o dwm.o util.o -s -L -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res
```

appears to have a `-L` option with no parameter.  Or, perhaps more correctly, it will assume that its parameter is `-lX11`.  I'm assuming this is because the variable `X11LIB` is unspecified in your makefile.  Not sure exactly how `X11LIB` is supposed to be specified with the makefile you're using but you could try setting it explicitly...

```
X11LIB := /usr/lib64 # Assumes the path to libX11.so is /usr/lib64/libX11.so
```

Comment: I changed ```LIBS = -L${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} ${FREETYPELIBS}  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res``` to ```LIBS = -${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} ${FREETYPELIBS}  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res``` (removed the L), and it compiled, but now it crashes, when I try to log into dwm, I get sent straight to lightdm again.

Answer (score 1):

```
-L -lX11
```

This means "add a directory named `-lX11` to the library search path". This is unlikely to have any effect as such directory probably does nit exist.

Remove `-L` or add a non-empty directory argument after it.

Comment: I changed ```LIBS = -L${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} ${FREETYPELIBS}  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res``` to ```LIBS = -${X11LIB} -lX11 ${XINERAMALIBS} ${FREETYPELIBS}  -lXrender -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lxcb-res``` (removed the L), and it compiled, but now it crashes