# Can't link against self built LLVM API

Tags: c, build, llvm

I need a feature from the latest repos for the LLVM API (version 13) so I've cloned the repo and built them to use instead of the older system installed LLVM files (version 12). For some reason though when passing the necessary flags provided by the instance of `llvm-config` built from the cloned repo neither GCC or Clang can link any of the LLVM API functions, having every single one come up as an undefined reference during the linking phase. Here's the command I'm running:

```
gcc -I. $(llvm-config --cflags) $(llvm-config --ldflags) $(llvm-config --libs all) code.c
```

Where `llvm-config` has been symlinked against the binary produced in the latest repo. If I switch back to linking against the older system files, the above command works just fine.

Is there any way I could had misconfigured the build for the LLVM repo, or perhaps a change between version 12 and 13 is getting in the way? Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit:

When moving the `code.c` argument to the start of the command I get many more undefined reference errors, here are the first 20:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86AsmPrinter.cpp.o): in function `llvm::X86AsmPrinter::emitEndOfAsmFile(llvm::Module&)':
X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm13X86AsmPrinter16emitEndOfAsmFileERNS_6ModuleE+0x259): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm13X86AsmPrinter16emitEndOfAsmFileERNS_6ModuleE+0x336): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86AsmPrinter.cpp.o): in function `llvm::RegisterAsmPrinter<llvm::X86AsmPrinter>::Allocator(llvm::TargetMachine&, std::unique_ptr<llvm::MCStreamer, std::default_delete<llvm::MCStreamer> >&&)':
X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm18RegisterAsmPrinterINS_13X86AsmPrinterEE9AllocatorERNS_13TargetMachineEOSt10unique_ptrINS_10MCStreamerESt14default_deleteIS6_EE[_ZN4llvm18RegisterAsmPrinterINS_13X86AsmPrinterEE9AllocatorERNS_13TargetMachineEOSt10unique_ptrINS_10MCStreamerESt14default_deleteIS6_EE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86AsmPrinter.cpp.o): in function `llvm::X86AsmPrinter::PrintSymbolOperand(llvm::MachineOperand const&, llvm::raw_ostream&)':
X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm13X86AsmPrinter18PrintSymbolOperandERKNS_14MachineOperandERNS_11raw_ostreamE+0x7c0): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86AsmPrinter.cpp.o): in function `std::_Rb_tree<llvm::MCSymbol const*, std::pair<llvm::MCSymbol const* const, std::vector<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo, std::allocator<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<llvm::MCSymbol const* const, std::vector<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo, std::allocator<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo> > > >, llvm::FaultMaps::MCSymbolComparator, std::allocator<std::pair<llvm::MCSymbol const* const, std::vector<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo, std::allocator<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo> > > > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<llvm::MCSymbol const* const, std::vector<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo, std::allocator<llvm::FaultMaps::FaultInfo> > > >*)':
X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E]+0xcc): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E]+0xde): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E]+0x104): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E]+0x111): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E]+0x139): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86AsmPrinter.cpp.o):X86AsmPrinter.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIPKN4llvm8MCSymbolESt4pairIKS3_St6vectorINS0_9FaultMaps9FaultInfoESaIS8_EEESt10_Select1stISB_ENS7_18MCSymbolComparatorESaISB_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeISB_E]+0x157): more undefined references to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86MCInstLower.cpp.o): in function `(anonymous namespace)::X86MCInstLower::GetSymbolFromOperand(llvm::MachineOperand const&) const':
X86MCInstLower.cpp:(.text._ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_114X86MCInstLower20GetSymbolFromOperandERKN4llvm14MachineOperandE+0x4ee): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86MCInstLower.cpp:(.text._ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_114X86MCInstLower20GetSymbolFromOperandERKN4llvm14MachineOperandE+0x5f6): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a(X86MCInstLower.cpp.o): in function `llvm::APFloat::Storage::~Storage()':
X86MCInstLower.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm7APFloat7StorageD2Ev[_ZN4llvm7APFloat7StorageD5Ev]+0x1bb): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: X86MCInstLower.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm7APFloat7StorageD2Ev[_ZN4llvm7APFloat7StorageD5Ev]+0x1d7): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*, unsigned long)'
```

Here are the exact outputs of `llvm-config --cflags --ldflags --libs all`:

```
-I/home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/llvm/include -I/home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -L/home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib -lLLVMWindowsManifest -lLLVMXRay -lLLVMLibDriver -lLLVMDlltoolDriver -lLLVMCoverage -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler -lLLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser -lLLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen -lLLVMWebAssemblyDesc -lLLVMWebAssemblyUtils -lLLVMWebAssemblyInfo -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMRISCVDisassembler -lLLVMRISCVAsmParser -lLLVMRISCVCodeGen -lLLVMRISCVDesc -lLLVMRISCVInfo -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMMSP430Disassembler -lLLVMMSP430AsmParser -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMLanaiDisassembler -lLLVMLanaiCodeGen -lLLVMLanaiAsmParser -lLLVMLanaiDesc -lLLVMLanaiInfo -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmParser -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMBPFDisassembler -lLLVMBPFAsmParser -lLLVMBPFCodeGen -lLLVMBPFDesc -lLLVMBPFInfo -lLLVMAVRDisassembler -lLLVMAVRAsmParser -lLLVMAVRCodeGen -lLLVMAVRDesc -lLLVMAVRInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMUtils -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen -lLLVMAMDGPUDesc -lLLVMAMDGPUUtils -lLLVMAMDGPUInfo -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMOrcJIT -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMJITLink -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMOrcTargetProcess -lLLVMOrcShared -lLLVMSymbolize -lLLVMDebugInfoPDB -lLLVMDebugInfoGSYM -lLLVMOption -lLLVMObjectYAML -lLLVMMCA -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMPasses -lLLVMCFGuard -lLLVMCoroutines -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMFrontendOpenMP -lLLVMFrontendOpenACC -lLLVMExtensions -lLLVMDWARFLinker -lLLVMGlobalISel -lLLVMMIRParser -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMDebugInfoMSF -lLLVMDebugInfoDWARF -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMInterfaceStub -lLLVMFileCheck -lLLVMFuzzMutate -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMAggressiveInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMTextAPI -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMMC -lLLVMDebugInfoCodeView -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMCore -lLLVMRemarks -lLLVMBitstreamReader -lLLVMBinaryFormat -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMDemangle
```

Trying compilation and linking with `g++` gives a new set of undefined references:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.cpp.o): in function `llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread_impl(void* (*)(void*), void*, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>)':
Threading.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm27llvm_execute_on_thread_implEPFPvS0_ES0_NS_8OptionalIjEE+0x4e): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Threading.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm27llvm_execute_on_thread_implEPFPvS0_ES0_NS_8OptionalIjEE+0x8e): undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.cpp.o): in function `llvm::llvm_thread_detach_impl(unsigned long)':
Threading.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm23llvm_thread_detach_implEm+0x5): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.cpp.o): in function `llvm::llvm_thread_join_impl(unsigned long)':
Threading.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm21llvm_thread_join_implEm+0x7): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.cpp.o): in function `llvm::set_thread_name(llvm::Twine const&)':
Threading.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm15set_thread_nameERKNS_5TwineE+0x4d): undefined reference to `pthread_setname_np'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.cpp.o): in function `llvm::get_thread_name(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char>&)':
Threading.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm15get_thread_nameERNS_15SmallVectorImplIcEE+0x3f): undefined reference to `pthread_getname_np'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Compression.cpp.o): in function `llvm::zlib::compress(llvm::StringRef, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char>&, int)':
Compression.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm4zlib8compressENS_9StringRefERNS_15SmallVectorImplIcEEi+0x2f): undefined reference to `compressBound'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Compression.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm4zlib8compressENS_9StringRefERNS_15SmallVectorImplIcEEi+0x50): undefined reference to `compress2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Compression.cpp.o): in function `llvm::zlib::uncompress(llvm::StringRef, char*, unsigned long&)':
Compression.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm4zlib10uncompressENS_9StringRefEPcRm+0x2d): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Compression.cpp.o): in function `llvm::zlib::uncompress(llvm::StringRef, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char>&, unsigned long)':
Compression.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm4zlib10uncompressENS_9StringRefERNS_15SmallVectorImplIcEEm+0x42): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Compression.cpp.o): in function `llvm::zlib::crc32(llvm::StringRef)':
Compression.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm4zlib5crc32ENS_9StringRefE+0xd): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(CRC.cpp.o): in function `llvm::crc32(unsigned int, llvm::ArrayRef<unsigned char>)':
CRC.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm5crc32EjNS_8ArrayRefIhEE+0x35): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(CRC.cpp.o): in function `llvm::crc32(llvm::ArrayRef<unsigned char>)':
CRC.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm5crc32ENS_8ArrayRefIhEE+0x35): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(CRC.cpp.o): in function `llvm::JamCRC::update(llvm::ArrayRef<unsigned char>)':
CRC.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm6JamCRC6updateENS_8ArrayRefIhEE+0x36): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::object_deleter<llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::HandleSet>::call(void*)':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm14object_deleterINS_3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSetEE4callEPv[_ZN4llvm14object_deleterINS_3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSetEE4callEPv]+0x29): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm14object_deleterINS_3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSetEE4callEPv[_ZN4llvm14object_deleterINS_3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSetEE4callEPv]+0x3c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::HandleSet::~HandleSet()':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSetD2Ev+0x21): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSetD2Ev+0x35): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::HandleSet::DLOpen(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSet6DLOpenEPKcPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x10): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSet6DLOpenEPKcPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x2e): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::HandleSet::DLClose(void*)':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSet7DLCloseEPv+0x1): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::HandleSet::DLSym(void*, char const*)':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary9HandleSet5DLSymEPvPKc+0x1): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::getAddressOfSymbol(char const*)':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary18getAddressOfSymbolEPKc+0xd): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::SearchForAddressOfSymbol(char const*) [clone .localalias]':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary24SearchForAddressOfSymbolEPKc+0x157): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary24SearchForAddressOfSymbolEPKc+0x284): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary24SearchForAddressOfSymbolEPKc+0x2c7): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o):DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary24SearchForAddressOfSymbolEPKc+0x3a8): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(DynamicLibrary.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::getPermanentLibrary(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) [clone .localalias]':
DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x3e): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0xfd): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x1e2): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: DynamicLibrary.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x2ba): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Process.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) [clone .part.0]':
Process.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys7Process23FileDescriptorHasColorsEi.part.0+0x50): undefined reference to `set_curterm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Process.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys7Process23FileDescriptorHasColorsEi.part.0+0x69): undefined reference to `setupterm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Process.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys7Process23FileDescriptorHasColorsEi.part.0+0xa8): undefined reference to `tigetnum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Process.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys7Process23FileDescriptorHasColorsEi.part.0+0xb2): undefined reference to `set_curterm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: Process.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys7Process23FileDescriptorHasColorsEi.part.0+0xba): undefined reference to `del_curterm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::~ThreadLocalImpl() [clone .localalias]':
ThreadLocal.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys15ThreadLocalImplD2Ev+0x12): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::~ThreadLocalImpl() [clone .localalias]':
ThreadLocal.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys15ThreadLocalImplD0Ev+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::ThreadLocalImpl()':
ThreadLocal.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys15ThreadLocalImplC2Ev+0x20): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::setInstance(void const*)':
ThreadLocal.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys15ThreadLocalImpl11setInstanceEPKv+0x4): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::getInstance()':
ThreadLocal.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys15ThreadLocalImpl11getInstanceEv+0x4): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/muke/Programming/Project/llvm-project/build/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.cpp.o): in function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::removeInstance()':
ThreadLocal.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys15ThreadLocalImpl14removeInstanceEv+0x6): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Assuming `llvm-config` produces desired paths, put `code.c` _before_ the commands, particularly the `--libs` one. Otherwise it may link to the old lib

Comment: wow, this actually worked, thanks!

Comment: Oh, nevermind sorry I had forgot to redo the symlink to the repo. Changing the order of code.c causes  far more undefined reference errors to be produced instead. There are too many to pastebin without exceeding the max size, but it looks like it's now including every C++ functions the API calls too.

Comment: When you rebuilt from repo, where did you _install_ it? Standard install would be in (e.g.) `/usr/lib64/llvm<ver>`. But, after (e.g.) `./configure`, the install dir for `make install` can be `/usr/local/lib64/llvm<ver>`. Ensure that `llvm-config` output matches the install dir. Then, consider splitting into two commands [in a script or makefile] (e.g.): `cfg=/full/path/to/bin/llvm-config-<ver> ; gcc -I. $($cfg --cflags) -c code.c ; gcc -o code code.o $($cfg --ldflags --libs)` If you put these commands in a makefile, `make` will print them. Or, if script, do: `bash -x ./myscript`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but `llvm` is usually associated with `clang`, but you're using `gcc`???

Comment: I didn't think I would need to install it because the llvm-config binary produced already points to the build directory. I'll give this and splitting out compilation from linking a try though. As I said in the post this error occurs for both Clang and GCC, but either way I'm only trying to use the LLVM API to build IR, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: If `llvm-config` points to the build directory, you are correct, you don't need to install it. Try the other script stuff I mentioned to see what happens

Comment: Separating out the commands has the compilation step with `-c` work fine but the linking step with `-o` fail with the same errors.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the errors in a separate code block here. If there are a _huge_ amount, perhaps only the first N error messages are needed. Also, in a separate code block, post the output of `llvm-config --cflags --ldflags --libs all`

Comment: Sure, added them now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefaced by the top comments ...

Aha! `llvm/clang` are written in C++ and *not* C.

The link is complaining about [amongst other things] not being able to resolve:

```
operator new(unsigned long)
```

This is a standard function provided by the c++ *compiler* [from an internal library]. It does *not* come from the LLVM libraries.

It was not resolved because you're *linking* with `gcc`.

Relink with `g++` [or `c++`] (e.g.):

```
cfg=llvm-config-<ver>
gcc -I. $($cfg --cflags) -c code.c
g++ -o code code.o $($cfg --ldflags --libs)
```

That may be enough.

Otherwise, you may have to rename `code.c` into `code.cpp` (i.e. *your* program may have to be C++ code) and compile it with `g++` as well:

```
cfg=llvm-config-<ver>
g++ -I. $($cfg --cflags) -c code.cpp
g++ -o code code.o $($cfg --ldflags --libs)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Both suggestions here lead to the same set of new undefined reference errors that I've edited into the OP. – muke

This *did* fix the C++ vs C issue.

There are some other symbols that are unresolved:

```
compress2 compressBound crc32 del_curterm dlclose dlerror dlopen
dlsym pthread_attr_setstacksize pthread_create pthread_detach
pthread_getname_np pthread_getspecific pthread_join pthread_key_create
pthread_key_delete pthread_setname_np pthread_setspecific set_curterm
setupterm tigetnum uncompress
```

The code is multithreaded and uses `pthreads`, and needs the library to resolve the various `pthread_*` symbols. So, add `-lpthread` to the *end* of the link command.

`crc32` et. al. are provided by `zlib`, so you may also need `-lz`.

Also, `dlopen` et. al. is provided by `-ldl` (the dynamic linking library).

And, `set_curterm` et. al. is provided by the curses library, so we may need `-lcurses` [or `-lncurses` instead]

So, I'd try:

```
cfg=llvm-config-<ver>
g++ -I. $($cfg --cflags) -c code.cpp
g++ -o code code.o $($cfg --ldflags --libs) -lz -lpthread -lcurses -ldl
```

You may have to jiggle the order of these `-l*` options if that doesn't work, but give it a try as is.

Or, as in lieu of that [as a last resort], you could put them in a linker group:

```
cfg=llvm-config-<ver>
g++ -I. $($cfg --cflags) -c code.cpp
g++ -o code code.o $($cfg --ldflags --libs) \
-Wl,--start-group -lz -lpthread -lcurses -ldl -Wl,--end-group
```

But, linker groups are [usually] more helpful with `.a` files that `.so` files.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Thanks for the edit, this was resolved most of the symbols. The last one is 'del_curterm', do you know which library provides this?

This is an extern in `-lncurses`. The way to see this is to look at the output of: `readelf -a /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.6`

> There's one more error after this too: /lib64/libtinfo.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line, I'm not sure what this means though. – muke

If you do: `ldd /usr/lib64/libncurses.6.so`, it will tell which [shared] libraries it needs. One of them is [surprise ;-)]: `/lib64/libtinfo.so.6`

As to the DSO issue, a google search on the phrase/sentence: `DSO missing from command line`, produces [amongst others] a link to:

[libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/libpthread-so-0-error-adding-symbols-dso-missing-from-command-line)

From that page, the issue is similar to your original problem of *not* putting the `--libs` argument as the *last* argument when linking.

One of the solutions from that page is to use a linker group as I previously mentioned (e.g.) wrap the `-l*` options in the [aformentioned] `-Wl,*` options:

```
cfg=llvm-config-<ver>
g++ -I. $($cfg --cflags) -c code.cpp
g++ -o code code.o $($cfg --ldflags --libs) \
-Wl,--start-group -lz -lpthread -lcurses -ltinfo -ldl -Wl,--end-group
```

Comment: Both suggestions here lead to the same set of new undefined reference errors that I've edited into the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this was resolved most of the symbols. The last one is `del_curterm`, do you know which library provides this? There's one more error after this too: `/lib64/libtinfo.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`, I'm not sure what this means though.